# Date is not saving in correct format controller in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

my controller's action

```
time = Time.now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
  # render text: time
 u=SectionMst.new( :section_name => params[:section_name], :date_added => time , date_updated => time)
  u.save
```

My modal code is

```
class SectionMst < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :date_added, :date_updated, :id, :section_name
end
```

render text:time is giving correct desired format but saving in %Y-%m-%d format 
not able to get WHY??

Answer (score 3):

The default `db` date format is: `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`.  You can check this by executing `Time::DATE_FORMATS[:db]` in your `rails console`.

You can update this format by defining the format of your choice in an initializer file inside `config/initializers/`.  Example:

```
# config/initializers/date_time_format.rb
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:db] = "%d-%m-%Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:db] = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"
```

Comment: on console i am getting "System can not accept the time entered".  I have also created the file in initializers and restart the server not working:(

Comment: @AmmarHayderKhan, can you post what you tried.  You can try `Time.now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")` or `Time.now.to_s(:db)`

Comment: i have tried with this and also many others...none is working... saves only  yyyy-mm-dd  format in db

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of your database, actualy DB support different format of dates, when you send date, after formatting it convert into own way so for avoid that use DB function to convert date. as `date_format(date, format)`

eg. `SELECT ProductName, Price, FORMAT(Now(),'YYYY-MM-DD') AS PerDate
FROM Products`

for making that sql query take an help from this link

[Format used when converting and saving a date string to database with rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886213/format-used-when-converting-and-saving-a-date-string-to-database-with-rails)